# SEO and reversed (key)words

Tags: seo, content, keywords, search-results

I am frequently finding sites that use reversed words in domain names and content. Just an example: www.elgoog.com or something like "Sincerely yours elgoog".

Does these word have value in SEO and SERP?
Is there any bonuses from them?
Does the search engines recognize them?

Where is the trick? Does their use really brings benefits or its just a placebo?

**UPDATE** - here are some examples:

http://lagug.typepad.com/ - this one is in Cyrillic
http://www.elgoog.org.uk/
http://www.oestsetnoc1.com/oes-tsetnoc-update/

Comment: Could you plz post links to sites you found doing this trick. I would like to see who's the one who had thought that this aberrant trick would bring any benefit to his site from a SEO point of view.

Comment: thanks. Except for the one in Cyrillic (PR 2), the other two have a PR of ZERO, so they didn't do a great job with the reversed keyword. Telling you the truth I'm surprised about the elgooG have such a ridicolous PR because even if it's a useless website, I would assume it's the typical thing might spread around quite easily, I mean people posting everywhere: "hey, cool look at Google reversed" and there with the link. Maybe it's just new, I saw it has 1000 friends on FB.

Answer (score 3):

There's no SEO benefit to this at all. Unless someone is looking for those backwards words there is nothing to be gained from doing this. The search engines do not tie them to the correctly spelled words as they are not synonyms.

Comment: Ok,  no benefits(just as I supposed) but why then it is so widely used. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably a variety of reasons: ignorance, fun, trying to capitalize off of a known brand name without trademark issues, etc.